# Access to directory through terminal - No such directory or file

Tags: command-line, 16.04, wine, lxterminal

Whenever I try to access a directory through the terminal I get the message "No such directory or file". I can easily access /home, but not /home/nico/etc.

I've also tried by copy/paste the directory like

```
cd /home/nico/.wine/drive_c/GOG Games/Fallout 2
```

But still the same problem. I am running Lubuntu 16.04.

Anybody could explain me why?

Comment: try `cd /home/nico/.wine/drive_c/GOG\ Games/Fallout\ 2` from terminal escaping spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Always quote the path that has spaces in it:

```
cd "/home/nico/.wine/drive_c/GOG Games/Fallout 2"
```

Comment: @Sweet_lumberjack If you are happy that Serg's answer definitively solved your issue you can 'Accept' it by clicking on the tick mark or checkbox near his answer.